# Docker-compose run issue

Tags: python, django, docker-compose

### I am faced with the error below. I have no idea to solve it. If anyone knows the solution, please help me...

Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "django-admin.py": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

■docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
nginx:
image: nginx:1.13
ports:
- "8000:8000"
volumes:
- ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
- ./nginx/uwsgi_params:/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
- ./static:/static
depends_on:
- python

db:
image: mysql:5.7
#MySQLの文字コードの設定です（defaultはlatin1が入っており、日本語入力ができないため）
command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
ports:
- "3306:3306"
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
MYSQL_DATABASE: todoList
MYSQL_USER: user
MYSQL_PASSWORD: mitsuki630
TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
volumes:
- ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
#./sqlを/docker-entrypoint-initdb.dにマウントすることで、コンテナ起動時に./sql配下のsql文が実行される（DBの初期化）
- ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

python:
build: ./python
#uwsgiを使用してポート8001（任意のポート番号）を開放します。これが、後のnginxへの連携の際に必要な処理となります
#app.wsgiのappはDjangoのプロジェクト名です
#--py-autoreload 1はDjangoアプリ開発の際に、ファイル等に変更があった際は自動リロードするための設定です
#--logto /tmp/mylog.logはログを残すための記述です。
command: uwsgi --socket :8001 --module app.wsgi --py-autoreload 1 --logto /tmp/mylog.log
volumes:
- ./src:/code
- ./static:/static
expose:
- "8001"
depends_on:
- db
```

■Dockerfile

```
#python3.6をインストール
FROM python:3.6
#PYTHONUNBUFFEREDでバッファーを無効にするらしい
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code
```

■requirements.txt

```
Django==2.0.4
uwsgi==2.0.17
PyMySQL==0.8.0
```

Comment: Do you have `django` in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Yes I have like this.


[requirements.txt]
Django==2.0.4
uwsgi==2.0.17
PyMySQL==0.8.0

Comment: I started from scratch. I made it. Thank you so much!

Comment: What was the problem?